# How do I align icons and text in center?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

How do I vertically stack and align icons with their respective text, and horizontally align them center? And make it all mobile-responsive?

[image]

My attempt

```css
li {
  margin: 0 90px;
  display: inline;
}

.num {
  margin: 0 150px;
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li i {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<ul>
  <li><i class="fas fa-phone">     
    </i>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-map">          
    </i>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-paper-plane">
    </i>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="num">
  <li><a href="tel:5551234567">Call (555)123-4567</a></li>
  <li>Box 564, Disneyland</li>
  <li><a href="mailto:EmailAddress@. XYZ.com"> Email.com </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is “front”?

Comment: Sorry I misspelled I meant Icons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this what you are looking for.

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
}

ul li i{
padding:10px;
}
ul li {
display:flex;
flex:1;
padding:20px;
flex-direction:column;
text-align:center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  ul {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
 </head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      <a href="tel:5551234567">Call (555)123-4567</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fas fa-map"> </i>
      <span>Box 564, Disneyland<span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
      <a href="mailto:EmailAddress@. XYZ.com"> Email.com </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass I would love to see brother.

Comment: Sorry but the Suggested edit queue is already full.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass can you share the codepen link bro?

Comment: You can use the snippet properly by putting CSS where it should be and HTML where it should be. You can remove all the redundant stuff like `.num` and `li` from CSS. You can also click "Tidy" to tidy up your code with correct indentations... To all this, you could use proper html practices instead of using the same bad practice list elements that OP used.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass thanks bro will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexbox wrapper with flex-direction row which switches to column using a media query and you could use flexboxes with flex-direction column for each item.

```css
#flexwrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.flexbox {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #569;
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #569;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  #flexwrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div id="flexwrapper">
  <div class="flexbox">
    <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></p>
    <p><a href="tel:5551234567">Call (555)123-4567</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox">
    <p><i class="fas fa-map"></i></p>
    <p>Box 564, Disneyland</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox">
    <p><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></p>
    <p><a href="mailto:EmailAddress@. XYZ.com"> Email.com </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```